# Summation of associative array element with certain condition

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, yii, associative-array

I have array in php like below

```
Array
(
[2015-07-22 09:00@#@2015-07-22 10:00] => Array
        (
            [17:30] => 1
        )

    [2015-07-22 10:00@#@2015-07-22 11:00] => Array
        (
            [17:30] => 2
        )

    [2015-07-22 11:00@#@2015-07-22 12:00] => Array
        (
            [17:30] => 8
        )

    [2015-07-22 12:00@#@2015-07-22 13:00] => Array
        (
            [17:30] => 3
        )

    [2015-07-22 13:00@#@2015-07-22 14:00] => Array
        (
            [17:30] => 1
        )

    [2015-07-22 14:00@#@2015-07-22 15:00] => Array
        (
            [17:30] => 0
        )
)
```

I want addition of element like 1st and 2nd element addition should get added then 2nd and 3rd should get added likewise so on.
I want array like this

```
 Array
    (
    [2015-07-22 09:00@#@2015-07-22 10:00] => Array
            (
                [17:30] => 1
            )

        [2015-07-22 10:00@#@2015-07-22 11:00] => Array
            (
                [17:30] => 3
            )

        [2015-07-22 11:00@#@2015-07-22 12:00] => Array
            (
                [17:30] => 11
            )

        [2015-07-22 12:00@#@2015-07-22 13:00] => Array
            (
                [17:30] => 14
            )

        [2015-07-22 13:00@#@2015-07-22 14:00] => Array
            (
                [17:30] => 15
            )

        [2015-07-22 14:00@#@2015-07-22 15:00] => Array
            (
                [17:30] => 15
            )
    )
```

I tried alot by using next and previous fuinction of php but it cant work for associative array as i wanted to be. Any one can help me to get array like this.

Comment: some code which you tried would be helpful.

Comment: The approach I suggested before I realized wouldn't work. I have a working version now that I'll post for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason this peaked my curiosity. This probably isn't the most memory efficient way to achieve the result, but I'm off to do my work now!

```
<?php

 $toTransform                     =   array
 (
   "2015-07-22 09:00@#@2015-07-22 10:00" => array("17:30" => 1),
   "2015-07-22 10:00@#@2015-07-22 11:00" => array("17:30" => 2),
   "2015-07-22 11:00@#@2015-07-22 12:00" => array("17:30" => 8),
   "2015-07-22 12:00@#@2015-07-22 13:00" => array("17:30" => 3),
   "2015-07-22 13:00@#@2015-07-22 14:00" => array("17:30" => 1),
   "2015-07-22 14:00@#@2015-07-22 15:00" => array("17:30" => 0),
 );

 $expectedArray                   =   array(
   "2015-07-22 09:00@#@2015-07-22 10:00"   =>  array("17:30" =>1),
   "2015-07-22 10:00@#@2015-07-22 11:00"   =>  array("17:30" =>3),
   "2015-07-22 11:00@#@2015-07-22 12:00"   =>  array("17:30" =>11),
   "2015-07-22 12:00@#@2015-07-22 13:00"   =>  array("17:30" =>14),
   "2015-07-22 13:00@#@2015-07-22 14:00"   =>  array("17:30" =>15),
   "2015-07-22 14:00@#@2015-07-22 15:00"   =>  array("17:30" =>15),
 );

 /**
  * @param array $array
  * @return array
  */
 function sumPreviousAndCurrent($array) {
   // the result we'll return at the end
   $result                        = array();
   $previousValue                 = 0;
   // loop through adding each element to the array
   foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
       // what is the first value in this array?
       $thisValue                 =   reset($v);
       // find out what the key of this value is
       $firstKey                  =   key($v);
       // figure out what the new value will be
       $newValue                  =   $thisValue + $previousValue;
       // set the value of the first element of this array as the new value
       $v[$firstKey]             =   $newValue;
       // set $previousValue to $newValue for the next pass
       $previousValue             =   $newValue;
       $result[$k]                = $v;
   }

   return $result;
 }

 // run the tranformation
 $result                          = sumPreviousAndCurrent($toTransform);

 // did it work?
 if ($result === $expectedArray) {
   echo 'Successfully transformed the array.';
 }
 else {
   echo 'Test failed.';
   ?>
   <strong>Input:</strong>
   <pre>
     <?php print_r($toTransform); ?>
   </pre>
   <strong>Expected Result:</strong>
   <pre>
     <?php print_r($expectedArray); ?>
   </pre>
   <strong>Output:</strong>
   <pre>
     <?php print_r($result); ?>
   </pre>
   <?php
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the data from @DomWolden answer as my test data.

It may be more efficient to keep a running total of the values so far...

[Working example at *eval.in*](https://eval.in/private/04425554858a8f)

The code:

```
 $prevRowTotal = 0; // accumulate current row values
 $outArray = array(); // output array in here

 foreach ($toTransform as $key => $valueArray) {
        $prevRowTotal += current($valueArray);
        $outArray[$key] = array(key($valueArray) => $prevRowTotal);
 };
```

Show the output:

```
var_dump($outArray);

// will throw execption if different
assert($outArray == $expectedArray);
```